# How to avoid leeching / hotlinking files?

Tags: nginx, hotlinking

I use [Kleeja](http://www.kleeja.com/) script to host files and noticed that certain files are downloaded many more times than the site's visit counter indicates. So I assume that the files are being leeched. The web server is Nginx.
Just wondering how to block leeching.

Comment: I found a nice solution for nginx here: http://tech.nocr.at/hacking-security/hotlink-prevention-in-nginx/

Answer (score 1):

It is traditionally done by disallowing access or redirecting when the referrer is from another domain.

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, including [using .htaccess files to redirect based on referrer](http://toomanysecrets.com/redirect-based-referer/). For nginx, [NginxHttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule)

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how can I do this using nginx?

Comment: The nginx rewrite directive is mentioned in the link above.